# Getting error while installing pods for existing project

Tags: objective-c, ios8, cocoapods

I am getting below error while installing pods for existing project.

```
[!] Unable to find targets named 'Project-Tests' to link with target definition 'Project-Tests'
```

Can anyone help me here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by adding new target in my project! Bingo!